# Close html5 HTMLNotification when link is clicked

Tags: html, webkit, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I am using `createHTMLNotification` for a chrome extension.  The html for the notification includes a link in it.  What im trying to figure out is how to close the notification when the link is clicked.  My code is following

```
var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(
    "notification.html"
);
notification.show();
```

The code on the notification.html page fills in the data.  This page includes the jquery library.  When I try to do:

```
$('#title > a').click(function() {
    notification.cancel();
}
```

This of course does not work because notification is unknown on this html page.  I have also tried to do a `notification.onshow` during the first part of the code where i create the notification, but this as well produced no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I figured it out.  It was actually a pretty simple fix. All you have to do is in the click event for the href in the notification, add `window.close()`.  This is because according to [W3C specification](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebNotifications/publish/WebNotifications.html) it is a separate window so you can treat it as such

Answer (score 2):

You can try following to set the focus to newly opened tab and close the notification on the way
`notification.onclick = function(x) { window.focus(); this.cancel(); };`

`notification.show();`